# click event on checkbox will not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the markup:

```js
$('.clsEvent input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
    debugger;
    var title = $(e).val();
});

This is the function that builds the list and is called in the document ready function:

function popServiceUserEvents(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetServiceUserEvents")/" + e,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.events.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {

                        $(".ulEvent")
                            .append("<li> <input class='clsEvent' type='checkbox' value='" + data.events[i].Value + "'/> &nbsp;" + data.events[i].Text + "</li>");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiEvent">
    <ul class="ulEvent" style="display: block;">
        <li> <input class="clsEvent" type="checkbox" value="3"> &nbsp;Event 1</li>
        <li> <input class="clsEvent" type="checkbox" value="4"> &nbsp;Event 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it doesn't matter if I change the event to click or change it to be in the form **...).on('change',function(...**
or if I just attempt the event against the class name without the type.

The page before I build the list is defined with this markup:

```
<div class="row eventDrop">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <dl class="myDropdown">
            <dt>
                <a href="#" style="color: #fff; font-weight: normal;">
                    <span class="topSection">Event</span>
                    <p class="multiSel"></p>
                </a>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="multiEvent">
                    <ul class="ulEvent"></ul>
                </div>
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove ` input` (including the space) from your selector.

Comment: changing it to `$('.clsEvent').change` still doesn't trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wrong Selector**

Your selector is wrong, you are searching a checkbox inside an element with `clsEvent` class

Those selectors are right choose the one you want ;):

`.clsEvent`

`input[type=checkbox].clsEvent`

`.ulEvent input[type=checkbox]`

**Trying to access `.val()` from `Event Object`**

Moreover `e` is an `Event Object`, your element is `$(e.target)`

```js
$('input[type=checkbox].clsEvent').change(function(e) {
 
    var title = $(e.target).val();
    console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiEvent">
    <ul class="ulEvent" style="display: block;">
        <li> <input class="clsEvent" type="checkbox" value="3"> &nbsp;Event 1</li>
        <li> <input class="clsEvent" type="checkbox" value="4"> &nbsp;Event 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried all of these selectors and it doesn't hit my debugger statement.

Comment: yeah I know var title is rubbish I just want to get to my debug statement to know it's going to get hit then i'll put the real code in place.

Comment: @bilpor is this answer working for you? If not then you need to post more code...

Comment: Agree with @evolutionxbox because if you run the snippet `change Event` is triggered.

Comment: no it's not :( I thought it might be because I'd placed it inside an anonymous function so I took it out of that, but still no joy.

Comment: @bilpor... then something else is wrong as the snippet in this answer works.

Comment: Here's the code that's actually on the page. The markup that I posted is what 's in the page after the the list has been built. `<div class="row eventDrop">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <dl class="myDropdown">
                <dt>
                    <a href="#" style="color: #fff; font-weight: normal;">
                        <span class="topSection">Event</span>
                        <p class="multiSel"></p>
                    </a>
                </dt>
                <dd><div class="multiEvent"><ul class="ulEvent"></ul></div></dd></dl></div>`

Comment: Maybe you trying to execute this script before that inputs are loaded

Comment: @evolutionxbox have placed the code in the question

Comment: this code change nothing. have you wrap your code in `$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});` ??

Comment: I also tried placing it in the document ready function and still no joy. I've also added the code I use to build the list, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: ... Put this code after your `for` loop inside the success callback.

Comment: @SteevePitis Wow. put it at the end of the for loop as you suggested and it works. Never come across that before. How come it works placing it there?

Comment: Your ajax call make some time to succeed, so you try to add an eventListener to elements which are not existing yet ...

Answer (score 1):

It's because your selector is wrong.

Try below :

```
 $('input[type=checkbox].clsEvent').change(function(e) {
    debugger;
    var title = $(e).val();

});
```

You are trying to get the input **inside**  the class .clsEvent and therefore not finding anything as your inputs have the class clsEvent.

Comment: I've tried all of these selectors and my debugger does not get hit.